# 4 equations with set of numbers

Tags: arithmetic

I must make 1 addition (x+y=z), 1 subtraction (x-y=z), 1 multiplication (x*y=z), and 1 division (x/y=z) equation with the following numbers. All the numbers must be used to fill x, y, and z of each equation. x, y, and z can consist be 1, 2, or 3-digit numbers.

`0`-4 available
`1`-9 available
`2`-1 available
`3`-2 available
`5`-1 available
`6`-1 avilalble
`7`-0 available
`8`-1 available
`9`-1 available
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit] this question to give some examples as to what e.g. an "addition equation" could look like?  And which part of the question are you having trouble with?

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones I updated it. Please tell me if it's still not clear. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  But there's 20 numbers available and these equations use three at a time.  That's a problem since 3 does not divide 20.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones I added one more thing: "x, y, and z can consist be 1, 2, or 3-digit numbers." Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic here, just guess and try.  I find $11+18=29, 11-6=5, 100*0=0,31/1=31$ as one of what must be many solutions.

Comment: Works for me. Thank you!