# 4 equations with specific set of numbers

Tags: arithmetic

I must make 1 addition (x+y=z), 1 subtraction (x-y=z), 1 multiplication (x*y=z), and 1 division (x/y=z) equation with the following numbers. All the numbers must be used to fill x, y, and z of each equation. x, y, and z can consist be 1, 2, or 3-digit numbers.

`0`-0 available
`1`-13 available
`2`-3 available
`3`-1 available
`4`-2 available
`5`-1 available
`6`-1 avilalble
`7`-1 available
`8`-2 available
`9`-2 available
Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting these from?

Comment: It's from a puzzle.

Comment: I really don't understand your question.First, by "numbers" do you mean digits? Second, you want to use them all up for three different equations?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes. What I need is 4 equations as defined above, where all four equations collectively use all the available digits.

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393922/4-equations-with-set-of-numbers

Comment: @vadim123 I know that's similar, but since there's no real formula, it's a trial and error thing that I'm stuck on.

Comment: @GiantDuck, I posted that link for others, not to suggest that this is a redundant question.

Comment: @vadim123 I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it:

1111*1=1111
89/89=1
12+12=24
76-35=41